# Fixing different id having same images in a csv column by renaming?

Tags: python

As a new Python programmer, I'm having trouble figuring out how to accomplish the following.

Given this input data from a csv file:

```
Sku     Image_Name
B001    a.jpg
B002    a.jpg
B001    b.jpg
B002    c.jpg
B003    x.jpg
```

Where multiple `Sku`'s might have the same image name. When that occurs, I want to rename the image name in the `Image__Name` column by concatenating `"_"` + `Sku` value as shown to the image name in that same row.

So the desired output data would be:

```
Sku     Image_Name
B001    a_B001.jpg
B002    a_B002.jpg
B001    b.jpg
B002    c.jpg
B003    x.jpg
```

After that it should rename the images in the image folder according to the `Image_Name` column.

This is all I have so far:

```
import csv

#open and store the csv file
with open('D:\\test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: So you want `a.jpg` to be renamed to two different names in the image folder?

Comment: yes, only if different sku has same imagename case becomes true

Comment: I think you missed my point. Generally speaking, a file only has one name, so it's not possible for `a.jpg` to be given two different ones.

Comment: @martineau I'm guessing (hoping) that the OP has images named `{name}_{sku}.jpg` for all the SKUs. Though I could be wrong.

Comment: @Wayne: I doubt it because of the part near the end where the OP wants to rename the files in the image folder accordingly. I suppose multiple copies of the same image file could be created with different names, but doing that really wouldn't make much sense either (IMO).

Comment: Ah, good point, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @martineau I'm at a loss for the last step. Hard links would (maybe) do it, but they're very system dependent and it's not clear what advantage they'd offer over the original situation. I find myself wondering if the OP has already accidentally overwritten a bunch of image files.

Comment: @Feneric: I thought of hard links, too, but neither they or making multiple copies of the original makes much sense to me—seems like two things with different Sku numbers ought to have _different_ image files associated with them (with different file names).

Comment: @martineau Agreed, that's why I'm wondering if the OP accidentally overwrote some images prior to posting the question here originally and is maybe looking for more of a way to undo that problem. It's hard to say what's really needed from the question itself.

Comment: @Feneric:  We could probably keep guessing indefinitely. However, until the OP clarifies things it's just moot speculation. This ambiguity is why I never bothered posting my own answer that addressed the initial part of their question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import os
from os.path import splitext # splits name & extension from a file
import shutil   #making a duplicate copy of a file
from os import rename


#open and read csv
with open('test.csv') as csvfile:

#create list for sku,old_imagename and new imagename
    itemList = []
    renamedList = []
    keyList = []
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

#processing every row at a time
    for row in spamreader:
        keyList.append(row[0])              #for sku
        itemList.append(row[1])             #for old_imagename
        renamedList.append(row[1])          #for new_imagename


#Processing only sku having same images
toBeChanged = [itemNum for itemNum, item in enumerate(itemList)
                if itemList.count(item) > 1]

for itemNum in toBeChanged:
    name, ext = splitext(itemList[itemNum])  # splitting image name & extension: eg a-> "a" & "jpg"
    oldFileName = name + ext
    print("oldFileName = " + oldFileName)    # oldFileName = a.jpg
    newFileName = '{}_{}{}'.format(name, keyList[itemNum], ext)
    print("newFileName = " + newFileName)    # newFileName = a_B001.jpg & a_B002.jpg


# check if the Image file exists,
    if(os.path.isfile(oldFileName)):
        shutil.copy2(oldFileName, newFileName);        # creating a duplicate image file
        renamedList[itemNum] = '{}_{}{}'.format(name, keyList[itemNum], ext)  #a_B001.jpg
        # os.remove(oldFileName)


#write the final output in new csv
with open('newCsv.csv','w') as mycsv:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(mycsv,delimiter=",")
    for row in zip(keyList, renamedList):
        print(row[0] + '\t' + '\t' + row[1])
        csvWriter.writerow([row[0],row[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, you've got quite a ways to go, but this should give you some hints on how to proceed (assuming a reasonable number of files):

```
import csv
from os.path import splitext

with open("/tmp/test.csv", 'rb') as csvfile:
    itemList = []
    renamedList = []
    keyList = []
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for row in spamreader:
        keyList.append(row[0])
        itemList.append(row[1])
        renamedList.append(row[1])
toBeChanged = [itemNum for itemNum, item in enumerate(itemList) 
                if itemList.count(item) > 1]
for itemNum in toBeChanged:
    name, ext = splitext(itemList[itemNum])
    renamedList[itemNum] = '{}_{}{}'.format(name, keyList[itemNum], ext)

# At this point we have your desired info and can print it just like you 
# have above
print("Sku\tImage_Name")
for row in zip(keyList, itemList):
    print(row[0] + '\t' + row[1])

# Duplicating / renaming files is next. This isn't the only way
# to do it (or the most efficient), but it's an easy way to understand.
# The idea is to first make copies of all needed files...
from shutil import copyfile
changedNames = []
for itemNum in toBeChanged:
    copyfile(itemList[itemNum], renamedList[itemNum])
    changedNames.append(itemList[itemNum])
# ...and then delete the originals. The set is used to eliminate
# duplicates.
from os import remove
for item in set(changedNames):
    remove(itemName)
```

There are *lots* of ways you can improve this code. The intent here was to make it more understandable. Understand it first, improve it second.

Comment: i have one image file ,i need to create another copy of it and rename according to the image column,,,, if you could please explain the logic ? thankyou so much

Comment: @sqllover999 As above. The east-to-understand approach is to make copies with the new names of all files needing to be copied and then delete the versions with the original names. Obviously it's more efficient to make one fewer copies in each case and do a rename in lieu of it, but that's a little trickier to get right. There's enough to learn in the above, so get that down first.

Comment: @sqllover999 Did you see the changes I made above per your comment?